# Can a the caster of Magic Fang designate a natural attack the target doesn't have?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

This question is related to a question about [Weretigers and permanent *Greater Magic Fang*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71598/12454), but not identical.

[*Magic Fang*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-fang/)'s description states:

> *Magic fang* gives one natural weapon or unarmed strike of the subject a +1 enhancement bonus on attack and damage rolls. The spell can affect a slam attack, fist, bite, or other natural weapon.

Can a human druid cast *Magic Fang* on herself and choose 'claw' as the type to gain the bonus (even though she has no 'claw' attack<sup>1</sup>)?

Is this simply a D.M.'s judgment call? or are there any citations backing up allowing or disallowing such use of the spell?

---

1: Obviously, she can't use the bonus without a claw attack, but the idea is that with *Greater Magic Fang*'s 1 hour/level duration - she can benefit from the spell later, when she decides, for example, to wildshape into a tiger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The caster of [*magic fang*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-fang/) typically can pick only a [natural weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#TOC-Natural-Attacks) that the subject already possesses to be affected by the spell…

What usually dictates whether a creature is or isn't a valid subject for a spell is a spell's *Target* entry (see Magic on [Aiming a Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell) on Target or Targets for details). The spell [*magic fang*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-fang/) has the entry *Target: Living creature touched*, but, upon casting the spell and subsequently touching the target, the caster picks "one natural weapon or unarmed strike *of the subject* [to receive] a +1 enhancement bonus on attack and damage rolls" (emphasis mine). Picking something that a creature doesn't have as the subject of an effect usually causes the effect to [fail](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Spell-Failure).

Thus I suspect that most GMs will rule that, while the spell's *Target* entry *does* mandate *only* that the subject be a living creature the caster touches, the spell's description increases the specificity of that *Target* entry to include "one natural weapon or unarmed strike of the subject," and if the subject does *not* possesses the natural weapon when the spell is cast, the spell fails.

#### …But this GM would likely let it slide anyway

However, the *magic fang* spell's *Target* entry is sufficient for *this* GM to rule that the spell doesn't outright *fail* if the caster picks a natural weapon the subject *doesn't* have to gain the spell's effect. Instead, this GM would rule that until the creature gains the picked natural weapon the subject's *magic fang* spell effect is present but, essentially, dormant, its duration counting down normally. This GM's ruling *is*—perhaps excessively—permissive, though. That is, if *this* GM can find *any* reading of a spell that allows a spell to work instead of to fail outright, this GM usually gravitates toward the reading that allows the spell to work. But were a GM to rule that spell *magic fang* functions in the traditional fashion—capable of affecting *only* an existing natural weapon—this player wouldn't flip the table and leave the campaign .

Answer (score 1):

### No.

The spell would continue as normal, but since the targeted creature had no natural weapons, the spell would have no effect, as you couldnt satisfy a condition on the spell effect at the time of casting. Like *casting Bear's Endurance on a zombie*.

However, if the creature is capable of using [Unarmed Strikes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/strike-unarmed/), then *that* should be affected, which is the case for most humanoid creatures. Since the spell does mention natural weapon *OR* unarmed strike as a valid effect:

> Magic fang gives one natural weapon **or unarmed strike** of the subject a +1 enhancement bonus on attack and damage rolls. The spell can affect a slam attack, fist, bite, or other natural weapon. The spell does not change an unarmed strike’s damage from nonlethal damage to lethal damage.